# C# change cell value of selected datagridview rows in database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

Hello i want to change the column of all the selected rows in datagridview and database but it is changing all of the data not just the selected rows.

This is how a populate the datagridview.

```
  private void dgvAuditAllSettings()
    {
        crud.FillDataGrid("Select AuditID,DateTime,Name,Position,Action,Status from AuditTrail where Status = 'Active' order by DateTime DESC", ref dgvAuditAll);
        dgvAuditAll.Columns[0].Width = 60;
        dgvAuditAll.Columns[1].Width = 200;
        dgvAuditAll.Columns[2].Width = 150;
        dgvAuditAll.Columns[3].Width = 140;
        dgvAuditAll.Columns[4].Width = 470;
    }
```

and how i want to change its Column value. But it is changing all of the row in database not just the selected row.

```
 private void btnAuditSendArchives_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAuditAll.SelectedRows)
        {
         // row.Cells[5].Value = "Archived";
            crud.AddRecord("Update AuditTrail set Status = 'Archive'");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed changing all rows in DB with this line:

```
crud.AddRecord("Update AuditTrail set Status = 'Archive'");
```

You didn't specify the id of the line, there is no `where` clause, so it will update all rows.

Try adding the id, it should be something like this:

```
crud.AddRecord($"Update AuditTrail set Status = 'Archive' Where AuditID = {row.Cells[0]}");
```

I use `row.Cells[0]` but it might be different depending on your implementation.

Comment: It has an error sir. It says "Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Whats the type of `AuditID`? Take the string out to a variable before sending it to the `AddRecord` function and examine its value, see if the query make sense to you

Comment: Its fixed sir. i first put the value of row.cell[0] to an int variable and used that int varible as ID. Thank you.